# Why is html_nodes() in R not giving me the desired output for this webpage?

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, rvest

I am looking to extract all the links for each episode on this webpage, however I appear to be having difficulty using html_nodes() where I haven't experienced such difficulty before. I am trying to iterate the code using "." such that all the attributes for the page are obtained with that CSS. This code is meant to give an output of all the attributes, but instead I get {xml_nodeset (0)}. I know what to do once I have all the attributes in order to obtain the links specifically out of them, but this step is proving a stumbling block for this website.

Here is the code I have begun in R:

```
episode_list_page_1 <- "https://jrelibrary.com/episode-list/"

episode_list_page_1 %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_node("body") %>%
  html_nodes(".type-text svelte-fugjkr first-mobile first-desktop") %>%
  html_attrs()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rvest down does not work here because this page uses javascript to insert another webpage into an iframe on this page, to display the information.

If you search the imebedded script you will find a reference to this page: "https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/eoqPA/66/" which will redirect you to "https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/eoqPA/67/".  This second page contains the data you are looking for in as embedded JSON and generated via javascript.

The links to the shows are extractable, and there is a link to a Google doc that is the full index.

Searching this page turns up a link to a Google doc:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

page2 <-read_html("https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/eoqPA/67/")

#find all of the links on the page:
str_extract_all(html_text(page2), 'https:.*?\\"') 

#isolate the Google docs
print(str_extract_all(html_text(page2), 'https://docs.*?\\"') )
#[[1]]
#[1] "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12iTobpwHViCIANFSX3Pc_dGMdfod-0w3I5P5QJL45L8/edit?usp=sharing"                                                
#[2] "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12iTobpwHViCIANFSX3Pc_dGMdfod-0w3I5P5QJL45L8/export?format=csv&id=12iTobpwHViCIANFSX3Pc_dGMdfod-0w3I5P5QJL45L8"
```

Comment: Now that is a level of confusion I was not expecting. Props to you for figuring that out! Is there any way for me to write code that spits out the link to the google doc, and then use the above code to access the links from the doc?

Comment: Yes, download the Google doc and save it as CSV, you can then use R to read the file and extract the links from the first column.  Another possibility is to use this `str_extract_all(html_text(page2), 'https://jrelibrary.com/.*?/') ` will extract links to the and navigate to the page. (the two list will most like not align exactly) It depends what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The purpose of this all is to write code that scrapes a web page for multiple documents. So in this case I have already written code that will give me a tibble containing the episode url, book title, and author in separate columns. The next step is to use the web page here listing multiple episodes and be able to iterate the function over each episode. The issue with downloading the document into a csv, although it does work, is that it defeats the purpose of automating the process and would not see me complete the assignment properly.

Comment: Since this website is heavily dependent on the use of javascript, it is not easily scraped with rvest.   There is a possible RSelenium method.  The question is how much time and work to program it versus performing some manual tasks.  Good luck with your assignment.